# Make bootable partition from a Live CD

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, gparted

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10, behind GRUB2. I'd like to add a separate bootable partition that I can use for partition editing and recovery tasks. I've downloaded the GParted Live CD and created an empty partition, but how can I put the GParted `.iso` on it and make it bootable from GRUB?

Comment: Have  you looked [Here](http://gparted.org/livehd.php) This article may help you.

Comment: No. That looks exactly like what I want, thanks. I've followed it now, but unfortunately it doesn't boot. Will try again later, or give up and use a stick :)

Comment: I will try this when I get home if I can get the time with my setup and let you know if I get it working.